# How to obtain php_phar.dll?

Tags: php, dll, pear, phar

PHP on Windows does not include **php_phar.dll** which means that

when installing pear i have to do it like this php -d phar.require_hash=0 go-pear.phar because it would not install Graph part of pear

I cant use MakeGood for unit testing in Eclipse

I cant use phar in general

is there a way to get to the php_phar.dll or pear community just decided that they wont support windows servers?

Comment: You don't need it:  https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47988

Comment: So the solutions is running  php -m, Brad can you make it an answer please so I can mark it?
Sunil - thats a compilation made for php 5.2 and it wont work with any other version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The phar extension is now a part of PHP that cannot be removed (statically built), so you do not need a .dll file for it.

Run `php -m` to see it listed.

Comment: if you have not registered php.exe as an ENVIRONMENT VARIABLE, you would need to run C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php -m